# Do OS X applications written in Mono have the same features as MonoTouch?

Tags: macos, mono, xamarin.ios, jit

What I mean by this is:

- MonoTouch integrates and binds to Interface Builder and the full Cocoa Framework.
- MonoTouch applications compile with the runtime, so there is no JIT, and no runtime needs to be present on the host OS.

Can OS X applications written in Mono take advantage of these MonoTouch features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new "MonoMac" is a wrapper to the native Cocoa libraries, just like MonoTouch, and integrates with Interface Builder.

I don't know if you can do full AOT to get rid of the JIT (since there's very little point on a full computer), but a runtime will be required just as it is for MonoTouch.  What it comes down is whether the runtime is separate or bundled with your application like MonoTouch.

I think with today's Mac App Store announcement, you will see Mono move towards making Mac bundles that are full contained easier.

http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Oct-20-1.html

Comment: thanks jpobst... yeah, I was thinking about it in terms of today's announcement. so can you currently bundle the runtime with the app? and.... does the MonoTouch tool which removes unused namespaces also work on OS X? cheers dude

Comment: Given the recentness of the announcement, I think it's still up in the air.  But yes, all of that is possible, it's just a matter of tooling to make it seamless for the user.  It also remains to be seen if Mono's LGPL license is compatible with the Mac App Store, or whether it will require a commercial license like MonoTouch.